# How to install phpcodesniffer engine to work with CodeClimate CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, code-climate

I'm just trying to use [codeclimate cli](https://codeclimate.com/platform) to analyze my code locally. I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.3 and, [as recommended here](https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate), I'm using [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io).

Everything good so far. I run `codeclimate init` to generate .codeclimate.yml file and tweaked it. It looks like this:

```
---
engines:
  phpcodesniffer:
    enabled: true
  coffeelint:
    enabled: true
  eslint:
    enabled: true
  csslint:
    enabled: true
ratings:
  paths:
  - "**.php"
  - "**.coffee"
  - "**.js"
  - "**.jsx"
  - "**.css"
exclude_paths:
- node_modules/**/*
- vendor/**/*
- etc/**/*
- .vagrant/**/*
```

After that I run `codeclimate engines:install` and this is my output:

```
Pulling docker images.
WARNING: unknown engine name: phpcodesniffer
...
```

Finally, `codeclimate engines:list` outputs:

`Available engines:
- bundler-audit: Patch-level verification for Bundler
- coffeelint: A style checker for CoffeeScript
- csslint: Automated linting of Cascading Stylesheets
- eslint: A JavaScript/JSX linting utility
- gofmt: gofmt
- golint: golint
- govet: govet
- rubocop: A Ruby static code analyzer, based on the community Ruby style guide.
- rubymotion: Rubymotion-specific rubocop checks
- watson: A young Ember Doctor to help you fix your code.`

What am I doing wrong? How should I install this engine?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `Code Climate CLI` needs to be updated if does not list out the engines it claims to support. To update you either can pull the latest docker image `$ docker pull codeclimate/codeclimate` or update your local git repo of CC and build image from there and execute make i.e. `sudo make install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (Code Climate) just recently released the `phpcodesniffer` engine, and your local Code Climate CLI version likely needs to be updated to know about it.

I just updated our docs to explain how to run an update: http://docs.codeclimate.com/article/301-code-climate-cli-troubleshooting#unknown_engine

Comment: Just to confirm, I did `brew update && brew upgrade codeclimate` this morning and didn't work. It worked now and upgraded codeclimate to `codeclimate/formulae/codeclimate 0.0.8`. codeclimate working perfectly. Thanks